# LaTeX: \equal not recognized within \section command

Tags: macros, conditionals, ifthenelse

I have the following code, where I want to steer the language of some titles and some texts using a "\newcommand". The following minimal example uses the new command "kLanguage", which is eng for english and deu for german.

Compiling using pdflatex or lualatex gives me the error "undifined control squence "\equal", but only when I use my macro "\deu" (or \eng) within a \section{} command. Outside the command it works how it should.

What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=17mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{ifthen}

%% use
%% deu for deutsch
%% eng for english
\newcommand{\kLanguage}{deu}



%% Text nur bei deutscher Sprache ausgeben:
\newcommand{\deu}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{deu}}{%%
{#1}}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end deu

%% Text nur bei englischer Sprache ausgeben:
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{eng}}{%%
{#1}}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end deu


\begin{document}

This works: Language is \kLanguage

This works:
\deu{Deutscher Text} \eng{English text}

But this does not work:
\section{\deu{Deutscher Titel}\eng{Englischer Titel}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\NewDocumentCommand\eng{m}` in place of `\newcommand{\eng}[1]` so that the command is robust

Comment: Something similar happened to me, awhile back. Turned out that `\equal` was being blamed for a problem that was elsewhere in the code.

Comment: changig to \NewDocumentCommand I get: ```! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 \NewDocumentCommand
                        \deu{m}{%```; oh, I have seen: package "xparse" does the trick. Thanks David.

Comment: @iGeeks A more modern (2021+) TeX distribution uses xparse automatically.

Comment: Instead `\section{\deu{Deutscher Titel}\eng{Englischer Titel}}` do `\deu{\section{Deutscher Titel}}\eng{\section{Englischer Titel}}`.

Comment: Be aware that defining a robust command via `\NewDocumentCommand` might not solve problems related to pdf-strings for bookmarks when using the hyperref package and applying the robust command in question within a moving argument of a sectioning command from which bookmarks might be created or from which an entry to the table of contents or the like might be created while at the time of applying `\tableofcontents` the macro `\klanguage` might point to a language other than the language it points to at the time of issuing the sectioning-command in question.

Answer (score 4):

In case a recent LaTeX distribution is in use I suggest using expl3's expandable routine `\str_if_eq:eeT` instead of the unexpandable routines of the **ifthen** package.

Reason: If the routine is fully expandable, it won't cause problems when occurring inside moving arguments and/or in places where pdf-strings, e.g., bookmarks, are created.

Compare the bookmarks of

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=17mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% use
%% deu for deutsch
%% eng for english
\newcommand{\kLanguage}{deu}
%\newcommand{\kLanguage}{eng}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%% Text nur bei deutscher Sprache ausgeben:
\cs_new:Npn \deu #1 { \str_if_eq:eeT {\kLanguage}{deu} {#1} }
%% Text nur bei englischer Sprache ausgeben:
\cs_new:Npn \eng #1 { \str_if_eq:eeT {\kLanguage}{eng} {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

This works: Language is \kLanguage

This works:
\deu{Deutscher Text}\eng{English text}

This does work:
\section{\deu{Deutscher Titel}\eng{Englischer Titel}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

with the bookmarks of

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=17mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% use
%% deu for deutsch
%% eng for english
\newcommand{\kLanguage}{deu}
%\newcommand{\kLanguage}{eng}

%% Text nur bei deutscher Sprache ausgeben:
\NewDocumentCommand{\deu}{m}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{deu}}{%%
#1}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end deu

%% Text nur bei englischer Sprache ausgeben:
\NewDocumentCommand{\eng}{m}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{eng}}{%%
#1}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end eng


\begin{document}

This works: Language is \kLanguage

This works:
\deu{Deutscher Text}\eng{English text}

But this does not work: % See the bookmark resulting from the command \section
\section{\deu{Deutscher Titel}\eng{Englischer Titel}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second example also delivers messages

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\deu' on input line 35.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\eng' on input line 35.
```

to console and .log-file.

---

---

If you insist in sticking to the **ifthen** package, do s.th. like this:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,margin=17mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% use
%% deu for deutsch
%% eng for english
\newcommand{\kLanguage}{deu}
%\newcommand{\kLanguage}{eng}

%% Text nur bei deutscher Sprache ausgeben:
\NewDocumentCommand{\deu}{m}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{deu}}{%%
#1}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end deu

%% Text nur bei englischer Sprache ausgeben:
\NewDocumentCommand{\eng}{m}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\kLanguage}{eng}}{%%
#1}{%%
}%% end ifthenelse
}% end eng


\begin{document}

This works: Language is \kLanguage

This works:
\deu{Deutscher Text}\eng{English text}

This does work:
\deu{\section{Deutscher Titel}}\eng{\section{Englischer Titel}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Ulrich. Actually both solutions work for me: \NewDocumentCommand and \cs_new:Npn. Using evince I do not even see a difference in the Bookmars. The solution \deu{\section{Deutscher Titel}}\eng{\section{Englischer Titel}} is not an option, because it causes too much explanation I have to instruct my autohrs of the chapters